# How to read the text of an intent

Tags: delphi, android-intent, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to read the text generated when sharing a place from Google Maps.  It is in this format:

> Empire Statet building New York, 10001, EE.UU. h t t p s://url

My idea is to open the URL internally in my app to get data from that place.

I've read intents without problem using this code:

```
function HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
  Extras: JBundle;
  valor,valorofuscated,id,typetoopen,valortext:string;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then
  begin
    Extras := Data.getExtras;
    if Extras <> nil then
    begin
      valorofuscated:=
        JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('EXTRA_TEXT')));  
      valor:= Crypt('Decrypt',valorofuscated);
    end;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

But, when I receive the intent from Maps, `Extras` is always nil. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know why `Extras` is `nil`, but you don't need to call `getExtras()` since you are not using the returned `Bundle`. Just call `getStringExtra()` unconditionally, and it will return `nil` if the requested item doesn't exist.  Also, you should be using `TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT` instead of `StringToJString('EXTRA_TEXT')` (especially since `'EXTRA_TEXT'` is the wrong string value, the correct value is `'android.intent.extra.TEXT'` instead).

Comment: I don´t get anything using `JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT));` :(

Comment: I wasn't expecting you to. If `Extras` is `nil` then `getStringExtra()` will obviously return `nil` as well. I was merely pointing out a bug in your code, which you have now fixed. So now, you need to figure out why Maps doesn't populate `Extras` with data when sharing a location. What data does the Intent actually contain? What is the Action of the intent? What Categories does it have? Flags? ComponentName? ContentType? Are you sure you are even processing the correct Intent that you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you, Remy. The problem is that I'm very lost with intents and I don´t know where to find information  about all of the questions you ask. I'm afraid that I have not the answers. All that I know is that if I share the place to clipboard, I see a text with the name of the place and a url pointing to google maps

Comment: Start with Android's [`Intent` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).  What the Clipboard app choses to extract from an `Intent` and convert to a text format for purposes of copy/paste *may not* be the actual format that is actually in the `Intent` itself.